# "The Object Type argument for the action or method is blank or invalid." error with blank form when opening from a control on another form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm attempting to create a control that moves from one form to another and goes to a specific record on the new form.  However I'm getting some odd errors that just don't make much sense to me (code wise).  Additionally, even if I open the form `frmService` from the object explorer window, I don't get the error but the form opens completely blank.

[frmService opened from Object Browser - Blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdJL2.png)
[frmService opened from control on frmWorkOrders - w/ Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IraFy.png)
[What frmService actually has on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dlGs.png)
[For good measure, a picture of frmWorkOrders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvGQO.png)

The control on `frmWorkOrders` that opens `frmService` is the button that is labeled "Service Record" and named `cmdService` (code below).

When I attempt to open `frmService` using a control on `frmWorkOrders` I get an error upon opening `frmService` stating:

> The Object Type argument for the action or method is blank or invalid.

The code to open and close the forms is pretty darn simple, so I'm not sure why it's having errors.

This is ALL the code on `frmService` which is where the error is occurring.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmService"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmWorkOrders", acNormal
End Sub

Private Sub cmdComputer_Click()
 Me.Computer.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdFirst_Click()
 Me.FirstStage.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdHPSPG_Click()
 Me.HPSPG.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdInflator_Click()
 Me.Inflator.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdOcto_Click()
 Me.Octo.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSecond_Click()
 Me.SecondStage.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command86_Click()
 Me.Computer.SetFocus
End Sub
```

And here's the code to open `frmService` and close `frmWorkOrders`.

```vb
Private Sub cmdService_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdService_Click_Err

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmService", , , "tblRegSR.[ID] = " & Me!txtID
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "frmService", acFirst, "[WorkOrderID] = " & Me.txtID
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmWorkOrders"

cmdService_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdService_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
   Resume cmdService_Click_Exit
End Sub
```

And just in case it's an SQL issue, here's the SQL statement for `frmService`.

```sql
SELECT tblRegSR.*, [tblCustomers].[FName] & " " & [LName] AS FullName, tblWorkOrder.Task, "WD0" & [tblWorkOrder]![ID] AS WONumber, tblFirstSR.*, tblHPSPGSR.*, tblInflatorSR.*, tblOctoSR.*, tblSecondSR.*, tblComputerSR.*
FROM ((((((tblCustomers RIGHT JOIN (tblWorkOrder INNER JOIN tblRegSR ON tblWorkOrder.ID = tblRegSR.ID) ON tblCustomers.ID = tblWorkOrder.CustomerID) 
INNER JOIN tblComputerSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblComputerSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblFirstSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblFirstSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblHPSPGSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblHPSPGSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblInflatorSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblInflatorSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblOctoSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblOctoSR.ServiceRecordID) 
INNER JOIN tblSecondSR ON tblRegSR.ID = tblSecondSR.ServiceRecordID;
```

Comment: What happens with `DoCmd.SearchForRecord acDataForm, "frmService", ...`?

Comment: I ended up having to redesign the entire table structure and form structure for both forms.  I got it opening up correctly, except there are other issues where I created a new question to address them.  I appreciate the help @GSerg.